# How to make a multistep command ask for inputs?

Tags: command-line, scripts, zenity

Sorry for the confusing title but here's what I want to do.

I run this command quite often:

```
w3m -dump http://www.example.com/file-to-save-as-text/ > ~/Desktop/saved-file.txt
```

Is it possible to have a (Zenity?) or plain terminal script that will allow me to paste in the URL `http://www.example.com/file-to-save-as-text/` and then prompt me to type in just the file name such as `saved-file.txt` after which `w3m` will "dump" the URL contents in `~/Desktop` with the file name I specified?

In other words, instead of typing in the whole command, I'll just need to paste in the URL (copied from my browser's address bar) and provide a suitable file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
url="$(zenity --entry "URL" --title "Enter the URL:" --text "Enter the URL:" 2>/dev/null)"
filename="$(zenity --entry "filename" --title "Enter the filename:" --text "Enter the filename:" 2>/dev/null)"
w3m -dump "$url" > ~/Desktop/"$filename"
```

- `url="$(zenity --entry "URL" --title "Enter the URL:" --text "Enter the URL:" 2>/dev/null)"`: prompts for the URL and stores the input in `$url`;
- `filename="$(zenity --entry "filename" --title "Enter the filename:" --text "Enter the filename:" 2>/dev/null)"`: prompts for the filename and stores the input in `$filename`;
- `w3m -dump "$url" > ~/Desktop/"$filename"`: executes `w3m -dump` on `$url` and redirects the output to `~/Desktop/"$filename"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter URL"
read URL
echo "enter filename"
read NAME

w3m -dump "$URL" > "$NAME"
```

You can save this as `run_w3m.sh`, make it executable with `chmod 755 run_w3m.sh` and run it with `./run_w3m.sh`.
The script will ask for the URL and the path to the file.